# How to import dataframe from another class?

Tags: python, pipeline, apache-beam

I want to import a dataframe from Class A to Class B. How can I do it?

```
class A:
    def process(self, input):
    return df

class B:
    def process(self, input):
        A = A(input_uri) 
        df = A.process(A, input)
        df.to_csv('path')
```

But I keep getting cannot the 'generator' object [while running '[7]: To CSV'].

Answer (score 1):

```
class A: 
    def process(self, input_df): 
        return input_df

class B: 
    def process(self, input_df): 
        a = A() 
        df = a.process(input_df) 
        df.to_csv('path.csv')
        
b = B()
b.process(some_df)
```

If I correctly get your question this is what you can do, if not please update the question and use code formatting to make it human readable.